# cannot call method appendChild of undefined

Tags: javascript

I  get this error when I insert a a href tag inside innerHtml in the javascript (flickrshow-7.1.js), for inserting a link for an image. Images are pulled from the flickr account using flickrshow javascript and displayed in the website as slideshow.

```
a.onLoadWindow = function() {
    a.elements.target = typeof a.elements.target === "string" ? document.getElementById(a.elements.target) : a.elements.target;
    a.elements.target.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com"><div class="flickrshow-container" style="background:transparent;height:' + a.elements.target.offsetHeight + "px;margin:0;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:relative;width:" + a.elements.target.offsetWidth + 'px"></div></a>';
```

Comment: `undefined` says it all. The node you're attempting to append to doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jared Code had no errors and was working fine, before I added the a href tag in this part of the code

Comment: @Jared link to the full javascript http://jmstvcamp.de/js/flickrshow-7.1.min.js

Comment: Do you have a non-minified version?

Comment: @Jared here it is http://jmstvcamp.de/js/flickrshow-7.1.min.js

Comment: @Jared Having changed the code, still getting the same error.cannot call method appendchild of undefined.

Comment: @Merryba I'm still looking for a non-minified version of the script. Nearly impossible to dig through a minified one

Comment: @Jared please look at my previous comment.I have given you the link for the non-minified version ot the script. Thanks

Comment: My mother always told me, read the error messages. They almost always tell you what the problem is. In this case, the problem is probably that, uhhh, you're calling `appendChild` on an undefined variable. Did you bother to look at this in the debugger? Do you know what a debugger is?

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` error means the javascript variable you are tying to call `appendChild` on doesn't have a value.  You need to fix the initialization so it has a value on which to call `appendChild`

```
<p id="parent"></p>

...

var newNode = document.createElement("li");
var parent; 
parent.appendChild(newNode);  // Error!!! What is parent?
parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.appendChild(newNode);
```

Comment: @Merryba can you be more specific?  Perhaps provide some sample code?

Comment: Got the newer version of flickrshow javascript and resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

An img element has no innerHTML, and you can not append a child node to an img.
Wrap the images in the a elements instead.